# error deserialization dynamic json

Tags: c#, json

I have the following Json , which has a dynamic set of values

> [   {
>       "Type": "Animal"   },   {
>        "Profession": "Dog"   } ]

I want to read it into an object

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<String,String>>>
```

this works :

```
var objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(rawStringJsonData);
```

but when I try

```
var objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<KeyValuePair<String,String>>>(rawStringJsonData);
```

I get an error

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read it as a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` and then cast it to 
`List<List<KeyValuePair<String,String>>>`

Try this:

```
var rawStringJsonData = "[ { \"Type\": \"Animal\" }, { \"Profession\": \"Dog\" } ]";
var dictList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(rawStringJsonData);

List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>> objectList =
     dictList.Select(i => i.ToList()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the debugger to inspect the type of your first try, its just deserializing to a list of [JTokens](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtoken.htm), and seeing as that you want a list of key value pairs I'd say that not really anything useful.

The List<List<KeyValuePair<String,String>>> datatype does not match your data.  That would *maybe* look something like this

```
[ {"Key": "Type", "Value": "Animal" }, {"Key": "Profession", "Value": "Dog" } ]
```

In this case I'd probably deserialize to a dictionary instead:

```
var objectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(rawStringJsonData);
```